# Haversine formula delivers incorrect result in Netlogo

Tags: gis, netlogo, haversine

I am using the gis extension of Netlogo and am trying to calculate distances between agents in km.
With `gis:envelope-of` I can get agent's positions in degree (!) latitude and longitude, so I want to use the Haversine formula to calculate distances. The projection of my underlying GIS-shapefile is WGS 84.

What I've written for two exemplary points is the following:

```
to haversine

let lata 31.8930795682288
let longa 36.0898369172224
let latb 31.9964498913126
let longb 36.0318329821497


let rad (pi / 180)



let result acos (cos (rad * lata) * cos(rad * (latb )) + sin ( rad * (lata) )* sin(rad * (latb)) * cos(rad * (longa - longb))) * 6371


print result


end
```

It yields a distance of 11.5 km, while the same formula applied in excel (using the RADIANS-formula instead of "rad") leaves me with 12.73 km, a number that this website http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html confirms.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This here http://bluemm.blogspot.de/2007/01/excel-formula-to-calculate-distance.html (and GIS as well as the link posted in the original question yield the same as this excel formula)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula that computes `result` is not correct.  It looks like you reversed `sin` and `cos`.  Use

```
let result acos(sin(rad * lata) * sin(rad * latb) + cos(rad * lata) * cos(rad * latb) * cos(rad * (longa - longb))) * 6371
```

Also, according to the docs that I've read (e.g. [`cos`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/cos.html) and [`acos`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/acos.html)), the netlogo trig functions use degrees, so the calculation should be

```
let result rad * acos(sin(lata) * sin(latb) + cos(lata) * cos(latb) * cos(longa - longb)) * 6371
```

Comment: Thank you for answering me! This however gives a result of 13.18 which is correct either...confusion!

Comment: I don't have netlogo installed, so I can't actually test it.  A translation to python gives 12.73, as expected.

Comment: I've just tried R, it also gives 12.73 - could this be a netlogo-specific problem?